# Effect stuck on first section

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

So I've used this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kySGqoU7X-s&t=46s idea for my portfolio webpage, but i cant make it to be on the whole page. It's stuck on the first section, after I've added some content in its div to avoid that. I want it to behave the same when someone is scrolling on my page, and by that i mean that the "blob" and the "blur" effect remains on the page even at the bottom not only and the top.

Does anyone know why it isnt?

```js
const blob = document.getElementById("blob");
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

window.onpointermove = event => {
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = event;

  blob.animate({
    left: `${clientX}px`,
    top: `${clientY}px`
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    fill: "forwards"
  });
};

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = e => {
  let iterations = 0;

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    e.target.innerText = e.target.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index < iterations) {
          return e.target.dataset.value[index];
        }

        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");

    if (iterations >= e.target.dataset.value.length) {
      clearInterval(iterations);
    }

    iterations += 1 / 4;
  }, 30);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0rem;
  --scrollbar-width: 0.4rem;
  --light-color: aquamarine;
  --dark-color: mediumpurple;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

#blob {
  background-color: white;
  height: 34vmax;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine, mediumpurple);
  animation: rotate 20s infinite;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#blur {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 10vw, 10rem);
  color: white;
  padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
  border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
  margin: 0rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  z-index: 4;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 5vw, 5rem);
  color: aquamarine;
  padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
  border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
  margin: 0rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 63%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  z-index: 4;
}

li,
a,
button {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  order: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav_links {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
  color: aquamarine;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: var(--scrollbar-width);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--dark-color);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--light-color);
}

h3 {
  color: var(--light-color);
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-size: clamp(0.5rem, 2vw, 2rem);
  padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
}

.spacer {
  margin: 10vh 0;
  height: 1px;
}

.section {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

.about p {
  width: 30%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
}

.highlight {
  color: var(--light-color);
}

th {
  color: var(--light-color);
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

tr td {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

table {
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
}

.socials-images img {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--light-color);
}

.socials-images li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.socials-images p {
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Zsolt Pál | FRONTEND</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="blob"></div>
  <div id="blur">
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="#about">About me</li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</li>
                    <li><a href="#socials">Socials</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 data-value="FRONTEND">FRONTEND</h1>
      <h2>Zsolt Pál</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="about">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="about">About Me</h3>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <p>In High school there wasn't any programming or developing teaching for me, so I've decided to take matter in my own hands. After a few weeks I've instantly fell in love with <span class="highlight">front-end</span> developing.</p>
        <p>Being able to create and modify <span class="highlight">webpages</span> and <span class="highlight">web applicitations</span> are are a huge interest in my life since then. I'm always looking up for new <span class="highlight">methods</span> and
          <span class="highlight">creative ideas</span>.</p>
        <p>Currently I am looking for a <span class="highlight">Junior</span> or a <span class="highlight">Trainee</span> job.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="projects">Projects</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              These are the projects that I've been envolved in.
            </th>
            <th>
              Some information about them.
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="hightlight">Name</span></td>
            <td><span class="hightlight">Function</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wiki about Cars</td>
            <td>Basically you are able to search for any car and make at this website, and it gives you back a bunch of information about the searched car.</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="socials">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="socials">Socials</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="socials-images">
          <ul>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter">
              <p><a href="https://twitter.com/palimadarxd">Twitter</a></p>
            </li>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
              <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/zsota02/?hl=en">Instagram</a></p>
            </li>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/github.png" alt="github">
              <p><a href="https://github.com/zsoltp2">Github</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use `position: fixed`. If you go to the far right, the "blob" expands the site and you can scroll vertical: [image]

```js
const blob = document.getElementById("blob");
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

window.onpointermove = event => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    blob.animate({
        left: `${clientX}px`,
        top: `${clientY}px`
    }, { duration: 3000, fill: "forwards" });
};

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = e => {
    let iterations = 0;
    
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        e.target.innerText =e.target.innerText.split("")
            .map((letter, index) => {
                if(index < iterations) {
                    return e.target.dataset.value[index];
                }
            
                return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
            })
            .join("");

        if(iterations >= e.target.dataset.value.length) {
            clearInterval(iterations);
        }

        iterations += 1 / 4;
    }, 30);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0rem;

    --scrollbar-width: 0.4rem;
    --light-color: aquamarine;
    --dark-color: mediumpurple;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        rotate: 0deg;
    }
    50% {
        scale: 1 1.5;
    }
    to {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }
}

#blob {
    background-color: white;
    height: 34vmax;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, aquamarine, mediumpurple);
    animation: rotate 20s infinite;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

#blur {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: clamp(3rem, 10vw, 10rem);
    color: white;
    padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
    border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
    margin: 0rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
    z-index: 4;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 5vw, 5rem);
    color: aquamarine;
    padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
    border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
    margin: 0rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 63%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
    z-index: 4;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    order: 3;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
    color: aquamarine;
}

button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: var(--scrollbar-width);
  }
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: var(--dark-color);
  }
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--light-color);
}

h3 {
    color: var(--light-color);
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: clamp(0.5rem, 2vw, 2rem);
    padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
}

.spacer {
    margin: 10vh 0;
    height: 1px;
}

.section {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.about {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

.about p {
    width: 30%;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}


.highlight {
    color: var(--light-color);
}

th {
    color: var(--light-color);
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

tr td {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

table {
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;

}

.socials-images img {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
}

.socials-images li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}  

.socials-images p {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="blob"></div>
  <div id="blur">
    <header>
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
          <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#socials">Socials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 data-value="FRONTEND">FRONTEND</h1>
      <h2>Zsolt Pál</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    
    <div class="section">
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="about">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="about">About Me</h3>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <p>In High school there wasn't any programming or developing teaching for me, so I've decided to take matter in my own hands. After a few weeks I've instantly fell in love with <span class="highlight">front-end</span> developing.</p>
        <p>Being able to create and modify <span class="highlight">webpages</span> and <span class="highlight">web applicitations</span> are are a huge interest in my life since then. I'm always looking up for new <span class="highlight">methods</span> and <span class="highlight">creative ideas</span>.</p>
        <p>Currently I am looking for a <span class="highlight">Junior</span> or a <span class="highlight">Trainee</span> job.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="projects">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="projects">Projects</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              These are the projects that I've been envolved in.
            </th>
            <th>
              Some information about them.
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="hightlight">Name</span></td>
            <td><span class="hightlight">Function</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wiki about Cars</td>
            <td>Basically you are able to search for any car and make at this website, and it gives you back a bunch of information about the searched car.</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="socials">
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3 id="socials">Socials</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="socials-images">
          <ul>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter">
              <p><a href="https://twitter.com/palimadarxd">Twitter</a></p>
            </li>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
              <p><a href="https://www.instagram.com/zsota02/?hl=en">Instagram</a></p>
            </li>
            <li class="social-image"><img src="images/github.png" alt="github">
              <p><a href="https://github.com/zsoltp2">Github</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```